# function concat comma separated in one single function

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario:

```
$(".table1 table tbody tr").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
    }
);

$(".table2 table tbody tr").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
    }
);
```

to avoid repeating the two functions to add remove the css, I would like to isolate the common part into a function. I tried this but I guess I'm having some closure issues.

```
$(".table1 table tbody tr").hover(
    self.setColor(this)
);

$(".table2 table tbody tr").hover(
    self.setColor(this)
);

self.setColor = function(context) {
    return (
        function() {
            $(context).css('background-color', 'antiquewhite');
        },
        function() {
            $(context).css("background-color", "");
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Why not put `.table1 table tbody tr:hover { background-color: red; }` in your CSS directly instead of using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about the problem wrong.

```
function onHover(event) {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}

function onLeave(event) {
  $(this).css('background-color', '');
}

$(".table1 table tbody tr").hover(onHover, onLeave);
```

You still need to pass two arguments, so make two functions and pass them individually.

Comment: Why not `$(".table1 table tbody tr, .table2 table tbody tr").hover(function () { ... }, function () { ... })`?

Comment: @melpomene yeah, that'd do it to. I was trying to solve the specific issue with OPs code, but that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a common css class rather than trying to simplify the function:

```
<script> 
     $(".my-table table tbody tr").hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "");
        });

</script>
```

Of course, you can even achieve this by a simple css style( I'm not sure if you deliberately avoid CSS):

```
<style>
 .my-table table tbody tr:hover{
   background-color:red; 
}
</style>
```